# Redirect to error page if hangfire authorization fails in asp.net mvc5 application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, hangfire

Can we redirect the user trying to browse hangfire url to some unauthorized page.
I am using ASP.net mvc 5.
I have the following page in my startup.cs file.

```
 public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            String conn = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.
    ConnectionStrings["conn"].ConnectionString;
            // For more information on how to configure your application, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=316888
            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration
               .UseSqlServerStorage(conn,
               new SqlServerStorageOptions { QueuePollInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1) });

            //BackgroundJob.Enqueue(() => Console.WriteLine("Fire-and-forget!"));

            //app.UseHangfireDashboard();

            app.UseHangfireDashboard("/Admin/hangfire", new DashboardOptions
            {
                Authorization =new[] { new DashboardAuthorizationFilter() }
            });
            //app.MapHangfireDashboard("/hangfire", new[] { new AuthorizationFilter() });
            app.UseHangfireServer();
            //start hangfire recurring jobs
            HangFireServices service = new HangFireServices();
            //service.StartArchive();
            service.StartDelete();
        }
```

The HangFireServices has the jobs:

```
public void StartDelete()
        {
            List<KeyValuePair<string, int>> c = _service.GetServiceRetention();

            foreach (var obj in c)
            {
                  RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(DELETE_SERVICE + obj.Key, () =>
                  Delete(obj.Key), //this is my function that does the actual process
               Cron.DayInterval(Convert.ToInt32(obj.Value)));
            }
        }
```

The authorization code is :

```
public class DashboardAuthorizationFilter : IDashboardAuthorizationFilter
    {
        public bool Authorize(DashboardContext context)
        {
            //TODO:Implement

                return false;
        }
    }
```

The default page is the Home page on which a different authorization class is set up. The user fails the authorization rules as per db and is redirected to UnAuthorizedController index page. If the user manually changes the url to point to /hangfire,as the authorization returned is false, it sees a blank page, but I want to redirect to UnAuthorizedController index page.

Comment: Just to clarify, do you want the user to _always_ see the `401` page or only when they fail to login to Hangfire UI?

Comment: Only when the user fails authorization, do I want to show 401 or some custom error page.

Comment: I've tried this with a web.config `httpError` entry and Hangfire seems to disregard this for some reason, even on login failure. Hopefully someone else knows how this can be intercepted!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to redirect to a particular page on controller, then may be this would help.

I created a account controller with login method as follows:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl = "jobs")
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        }

            var user = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(model.UserName);

            await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, false, false);        

            var virtualDirectory = Request.ApplicationPath.Equals("/") ? "/" : Request.ApplicationPath + "/";       

            return Redirect(virtualDirectory + returnUrl);
        }

        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
        return View(model);
    }
```

In my Startup.Auth.cs, I did following changes:

```
        public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
            app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>
             (ApplicationUserManager.Create);
            app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>
              (ApplicationSignInManager.Create);


            // Configure the sign in cookie
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
                CookieName = "TestService",
                LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
                SlidingExpiration = true,
                ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20000),
                Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider()
            });
        }
```

And finally, in the startup.cs class:

```
public partial class Startup
    {    
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {

            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
                LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login")
            });


            LogProvider.SetCurrentLogProvider(new HangfireLogProvider());

            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseSqlServerStorage("HangfirePersistence");

            app.UseHangfireDashboard("/jobs", new DashboardOptions
            {
                Authorization = new[] { new HangfireAuthFilter() }
            });

            app.UseHangfireServer();

            ConfigureAuth(app);
        }
    }

public class HangfireAuthFilter : IDashboardAuthorizationFilter
{
    public bool Authorize(DashboardContext context)
    {
        var user = HttpContext.Current.User;

        return user != null && user.IsInRole("Admin") && user.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
    }
}
```

When ever you are not authenticated, you will be redirected to the login action on account controller.

Answer (score 0):

If the error page represents static content - it's simple:

```
public class HangfireAuthorizationFilter : IDashboardAuthorizationFilter
{
    public bool Authorize([NotNull] DashboardContext context)
    {
        var path = context.GetHttpContext().Request.Path;
        var isResource = path != null && (path.Value.StartsWith("/css") || path.Value.StartsWith("/js") || path.Value.StartsWith("/font"));
        if (!context.GetHttpContext().User.Identity.IsAuthenticated && !isResource)
        {
            context.Response.ContentType = "text/html";
            context.Response.WriteAsync(new AccessDeniedPage().ToString(context.GetHttpContext()));
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Please make a note this `AccessDeniedPage` is not inherited from `Hangfire.Dashboard.RazorPage`. The reason is that you won't be able to assign current `context` to such page (**Hangfire** has made some its functionality `internal`). But if you need to inherit from `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorPage` for instance, it will looks something like:

```
context.Response.WriteAsync(new AccessDeniedPage().ToString(context.GetHttpContext()));
```

where `ToString` is:

```
public abstract class PageBase : RazorPage
{
    public UrlHelper Url { get; set; }

    public override async Task ExecuteAsync()
    {
        await Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public abstract void Execute();

    public string ToString(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        using var output = new StringWriter();
        ViewContext = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.ViewContext()
        {
            HttpContext = httpContext,
            Writer = output
        };
        HtmlEncoder = HtmlEncoder.Default;
        Url = new UrlHelper(new ActionContext
        {
           HttpContext = httpContext,
           ActionDescriptor = new ActionDescriptor(),
           RouteData = new RouteData()
        });
        Execute();
        return output.ToString();
    }
```